# Modifying DataFrames does not keep the columns I specify

Tags: python, dataframe, function

I have a list of dataframes that all contain similar columns such as Latitude, Longitude, and datetimes.  I'm trying to pass each dataframe thorugh a function to get the mean temperature for all time periods.  Then I'm trying to only keep the Latitude, Longitude, and temp columns for each dataframe.  The code below works to find the mean temperature for each dataframe but it won't drop the datetime columns I no longer need and I'm not sure why.

```
    def meantemp(df):
        df['temp'] = df.iloc[ : , 2:].mean(axis = 1)
        df = df[['Latitude','Longitude','temp']]
        return df

    weather_list = [df.pipe(meantemp) for df in weather_list]
```

This does return the correct dataframes to the list but will not modify the dataframes outside of the list.  I need use the dataframes separately later on in my program
Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

the df passed to meantemp is local to the function. So the return will give you the right list but if you need the modification to reflect to your df, reassign it to df instead of weather_list or use global df in meantemp function